# Why is my after_save callback stopping my ActiveRecord association from saving properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

When I comment out my `after_save` call back, my ActiveRecord associations work just fine. In Rails Console, you'd see:

```
> @report = Report.create :name => "foo"
=> #<Report id: 9, name: "foo", created_at: "2013-03-05 09:51:55", updated_at: "2013-03-05 09:51:55"> 
> @question = @report.questions.create :description => "bar"
=> #<Question id: 18, standard_id: nil, description: "bar", element_id: nil, condition_id: nil, blueprint_name: nil, blueprint_url: nil, created_at: "2013-03-05 09:52:32", updated_at: "2013-03-05 09:52:32", additive: false, instructions: nil> 
> @report.questions
=> [#<Question id: 18, standard_id: nil, description: "bar", element_id: nil, condition_id: nil, blueprint_name: nil, blueprint_url: nil, created_at: "2013-03-05 09:52:32", updated_at: "2013-03-05 09:52:32", additive: false, instructions: nil>] 
> @question.reports
=> [#<Report id: 9, name: "foo", created_at: "2013-03-05 09:51:55", updated_at: "2013-03-05 09:51:55">]
```

However, the associations stop working when I add the following `after_save` callback to `question.rb`:

```
  def create_matching_surveys
    self.reports.each do |report|
      report.reviews.each do |review|
        review.competitors.each do |competitor|
          competitor.surveys.find_or_create_by_question_id(self.id)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Then, in Rails Console, you get:

```
> @report = Report.create :name => "foo"
=> #<Report id: 13, name: "foo", created_at: "2013-03-05 10:20:51", updated_at: "2013-03-05 10:20:51">
> @question = @report.questions.create :description => "bar"
=> #<Question id: 24, standard_id: nil, description: "bar", element_id: nil, condition_id: nil, blueprint_name: nil, blueprint_url: nil, created_at: "2013-03-05 10:21:02", updated_at: "2013-03-05 10:21:02", additive: false, instructions: nil> 
> @report.questions
=> [#<Question id: 24, standard_id: nil, description: "bar", element_id: nil, condition_id: nil, blueprint_name: nil, blueprint_url: nil, created_at: "2013-03-05 10:21:02", updated_at: "2013-03-05 10:21:02", additive: false, instructions: nil>] 
> @question.reports
=> []
```

This happens whether or not the report has reviews that have competitors.

The strange thing is I thought the callback was meant to happen after the question was saved? So by rights the association should save too before any of this happens, right?

How do I fix it?

**UPDATE**

I think I have to call the callback in the right spot in the object's life cycle, but I can't find that spot. Here's why I think this:

```
> @report = Report.create :name => "foo"
=> #<Report id: 20, name: "foo", created_at: "2013-03-05 12:29:35", updated_at: "2013-03-05 12:29:35"> 
> @question = @report.questions.create :description => "bar"
=> #<Question id: 31, standard_id: nil, description: "bar", element_id: nil, condition_id: nil, blueprint_name: nil, blueprint_url: nil, created_at: "2013-03-05 12:30:14", updated_at: "2013-03-05 12:30:14", additive: false, instructions: nil> 
> @question.reports
 => [] 
> @question.update_attributes :description => "foo"
=> true 
> @question.reports
=> [#<Report id: 20, name: "foo", created_at: "2013-03-05 12:29:35", updated_at: "2013-03-05 12:29:35">]
```

BTW, the method is now in question_observer.rb:

```
class QuestionObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  def after_save(model)
    model.reload
    model.reports.reload
    model.reports.each do |report|
      report.reviews.each do |review|
        review.competitors.each do |competitor|
          competitor.surveys.find_or_create_by_question_id(model.id)
        end
      end
    end
    return true
  end

end
```

Comment: I'm sorry apneadiving but I don't understand. Where/how/why would I try to return true?

Comment: return true at the end of your callback

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get this to work. I tried putting "return true" inside the callback, on a new line just before the final "end". Is that what you meant? @question.reports is still []

Comment: that's what I meant, it's important to return a truthy value. Are you sre the error stems from this callback?

Comment: Absolutely. The error vanishes as soon as I comment out `after_save :create_matching_surveys` in `question.rb`.

Comment: sounds crazy, even `@question.reload.reports` is empty?

Comment: @question.reload.reports is NOT empty! So you must be on to something there now. I'll read up on the reload method now as I've not heard of it before. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: it just strikes the db again. Not sure why your object is not directly set properly

Comment: Tried adding `self.reload` and `self.reports.reload` to the start of `create_matching_surveys`, but it's still not working... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use a neat new callback hook called `after_commit` which was introduced with Rails 3.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_commit.

The only issue is `after_commit` doesn't work "out of the box" with transactional fixtures, but there are plenty of solutions out there, and I found this one worked well for me: https://supportbee.com/devblog/2012/01/14/testing-after_commitafter_transaction-with-rspec/